# Observable DataTable with RowCount and Results as separate fields

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-observables, angular-datatables

I am trying to refine my UI to use observables, and followed the blog here for my datatables: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/

In the end, I wound up with something like this in my `ItemService`

```
queryItems(filter = '', sortCol = 'Name', sortDirection = 'asc', pageNumber = 0, pageSize = 3):  Observable<ItemModel[]> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:31150/api/item/query', {
        params: new HttpParams()
            .set('search', filter)
            .set('orderBy', sortCol)
            // etc...
    }).pipe(
        map(res => res["Results"])
    );
}
```

My actual `res` result is an object with a lot of details.  Two such details are a `MaxRowCount` property, which is the TOTAL possible results (unpaged/unfiltered).  And the actual `Results` object, which is the true `ItemModel[]`. (Plus other fields irrelevant here)

The only reason this works is because it is returning an Observable with my `"Results"` object.  However, I am now missing my `MaxRowCount` object.

I would rather not have to expose a completely different API endpoint that just returns the MaxRowCount.  I especially like that whenever a person sorts, filters, or otherwise refreshes the `Observable`, that the latest and greatest MaxRowCount is available to them.

So how do I get that MaxRowCount from the `Observable` in my `ItemService`, through the command in my `DataSource<ItemModel>`, and into my `Item Component`?

My DataSource:

```
queryItems(filter = '', sortCol = 'Name', sortDirection = 'asc', pageIndex = 0, pageSize = 3) {
  this.loadingSubject.next(true);

  this.itemService.queryItems(filter, sortCol, sortDirection, pageIndex, pageSize).pipe(
      catchError(() => of([])),
      finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false))
  )
  .subscribe(items => {
    this.itemSubject.next(items);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking your result (which is an object which has both your results in `Results` and `MaxRowCount` and you are mapping it to an array of only ItemModel objects. You can map (in `ItemService`) to an object which contains both:

```
queryItems(filter = '', sortCol = 'Name', sortDirection = 'asc', pageNumber = 0, pageSize = 3):  Observable<QueryResult> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:31150/api/item/query', {
        params: new HttpParams()
            .set('search', filter)
            .set('orderBy', sortCol)
            // etc...
    }).pipe(
        map(res => ({ 
          rows: res["Results"],
          maxRowCount: res["MaxRowCount"] }))
    );
}

export interface QueryResult {
  rows: ItemModel[],
  maxRowCount: number
}
```

and then in your DataSource you can either subscribe twice, and then get the MaxRowCount in one observable and the rows in the second, or you can separate what you need and save it on a private state inside the component

Comment: My DS `implements DataSource<ItemModel>` with a `connect` method of type `Observable<ItemModel[]>`. The pub/sub happens through MatDataTables lib, so I don't personally directly sub to the `itemSubject`.  However, I **CAN** change my DataSource's `queryItems` method to look like this: `.subscribe(items => { this.itemSubject.next(items["Results"]); this.itemCountSubject.next(items["MaxRowCount"]); });`. There, I am now raising an event for my new `itemCountSubject`. But how do I "double subscribe" to get that event in my Component?  Or, if it's easier, to get it into my `mat-paginator` in HTML?

Comment: So what I did was add another method similar to the `connect`, an `Observable<number>` (obviously?), and just subscribed to it in my component.ts `ngOnInit`.  The new method just says `return this.itemCountSubject.asObservable();`